# In UWP application, how to reproduce exception telling that synchronous UI is allowed on non-UI threads only

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp

I can't figure out how threads of different types behave in UWP applications. First, in UWP it seems that UI thread is not a main thread, it's one of worker threads (I see this in the debugger when inserting breakpoints in event handlers and so on). My assumption is that `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess` designates if the current thread a UI thread or not.

From my understanding some actions should behave differently depending on the type of the current thread. In particular, synchronous I/O methods should raise an exception that synchronous I/O is not allowed on UI thread.

For instance, File.Exists, File.Move or creating a file with FileStream constructor. I even actually got these exceptions earlier but now can't figure out how to reproduce them again. They all are mysteriously gone. Even if I put these methods directly in a button.Click handler (which executes on UI thread, I believe, `HasThreadAccess` is true), they still work.

I believe this code kept throwing InvalidOperationException back in 2016 Dec when I tested it last time:

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "log.txt")))
    {
    }
```

Or, maybe, the code was close but not equal to that, maybe I'm missing some important detail..

I need to find a way to make these exceptions reliably occur again so that I could correctly refactor the old synchronous library to async and test it thoroughly. Without exceptions being thrown, I can't actually be sure that on someone's else system this library won't crash due to these I/O threading issues.

Comment: Your question starts out with the wrong assumption altogether. Windows does not maintain the concept of a *main thread* (that's an unfortunate simplification in the .NET framework). There are GUI threads and non-GUI thread. Any non-GUI thread can be propagated to a GUI thread, when that thread calls a User32.dll export for the first time. With that out of the way, what is your real question?

Comment: The question would be "how to make an UWP app throw exception that synchronous I/O is not allowed on UI thread" (I don't remember the exact text but "UI thread" phrase was certainly there). I got this exception many times when calling synchronous I/O methods in UWP but now I can't.

Comment: I also see Main thread category (and one thread matching this category) in Visual Studio debugger of my app although I have no idea what exactly it means there.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. For some weird reason, synchronous methods of System.IO namespace behave differently (in terms of threading) for disk folders in different locations.

This works:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "log.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

The below crashes with 'System.InvalidOperationException' and message 'Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread.  Consider wrapping this method in Task.Run':

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

At the same time, if I run the latter on a worker thread rather than UI thread, I get accurate UnauthorizedAccessException telling me that Access is denied.

I.e. it seems that prohibition to run synchronous operations on UI thread does NOT concern folders (at least ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder) where this I/O is allowed and does concern folders where this I/O is not allowed anyway. Maybe a bug in .NET code for UWP that wrong exception is thrown?

That's strange as I believe it should be no relation between threading and access control matters but at least I found a way to make UWP sync method crash in the way I needed.

EDIT:

Turns out it's the correct and expected behavior. When on UI thread, WinRT won't even try to access resources outside LocalFolder because it would cause internal deadlock (that's just how WinRT works under the hood). For LocalFolder access, using UI thread for sync I/O is allowed. That's why I'm getting InvalidOperationException (rather than UnauthorizedAccessException) on UI thread only when accessing resources outside LocalFolder.

The problem with UI thread will be with an object like file picker which can return location outside of LocalFolder (brokered file). Accessing such file on a worker thread won't throw UnauthorizedAccessException and will go just fine but on a UI thread we'll get InvalidOperationException because the file is outside LocalFolder. So, brokered files can only be accessed from a worker thread (either via natively async methods or via sync methods on a dedicated worker thread).

Comment: In UWP app doesn't have privileges to operate on other folder than LocalData. Therefore accessing via path is not a good idea. Use pickers to gain access to files. It has nothing to do with threads - simply you don't have access to open the file.

Comment: @Romasz That's exactly what I'm telling. UWP is expected to throw UnauthorizedAccessException in case if "C:\Temp\log.txt" is accessed. Instead, I'm getting InvalidOperationException telling me that this operation is not allowed on UI thread! At the same time, I get UnauthorizedAccessException (as expected) when the same operation and the same path is used on a worker thread. Also, at the same time if  I use the same operation and LocalFolder path on UI thread, I don't get any 'Synchronous operations should not be performed on the UI thread'. I think on a UI thread UWP throws wrong exception.

Comment: Ok, now I think I get what you have on your mind. If you have some time, maybe taking a look at [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#e23a38af5d11ddd3) will give you some answers.

Comment: InvalidOperationException is not there. Neither it appears at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx I guess it's because it's UWP specific case. It does not occur in FileStream when normal .NET Framework is being used.

Comment: Got it. Reference source should be this one: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/WinRTFileSystem.cs It turns out that only accessing locations outside LocalData cannot run on UI thread while within LocalData using sync methods like File.Exists is just fine on UI thread. Outside LocalData (when on UI thread) it even does not try to do anything and never reaches the point where it could throw UnauthorizedAccessException, for example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing research. Taking a look at the corefx source, seems like you are right. From the other hand you can always access a file via *StorageFile* - why not to do that?

Comment: @Romasz Actually, I'm developing a UWP lib, not an app. App is just for testing. I need to be prepared to accept Stream which came from any source. Maybe the app writer who'll call my library uses StorageFile as a Stream source or maybe not. I'm just checking all possible options to find out if I can use this or that mechanism for file I/O. More exactly, I'm porting normal .NET library to UWP and finding which places need correction and which can be left as-is for now. Lib has lot of sync I/O so I need to understand which parts must be rewritten to async right away (before the release).

Comment: As I think - if you pass a stream to a method then you don't need to open a file there - am I right?

Comment: Also the library allows the caller to specify file path (there are overloads which accept Stream and filename).

Comment: Then the methods from the library won't probably work with UWP aps, hence they will throw exception due to unauthorized access.

Comment: From my tests, they work with paths like `Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "log.txt")` (within LocalFolder).

Comment: For LocalFolder they may work, but you also cannot guarantee that it will work in future. Maybe you should force the user of the library to pass the stream, by not accepting the path.

Comment: Yes, this is my intention for this lib on a longer term.