# How to Find UI thread in UWP

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, uwp, system.reactive

I am Trying to Understand How Threading Works in UWP.

The Knowledge that I have is:

1) Each Application Window will have an UI thread. And many Worker(or Background) threads.

2) UI elements can be Accessed only through UI Thread. One can Do all the Memory Intensive Computations in Background Threads and Just Assign the Values to UI thread to Keep UI Responsive.

For this,
***CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(()=> method)*** is Used.

3) To Check Whether the thread is UI thread or a Non-UI thread, ***CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess*** can be used.(As Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809930/in-uwp-application-how-to-reproduce-exception-telling-that-synchronous-ui-is-al)

But,

When I try to use CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess, It Returns True in Most of the cases.(Even from Worker Threads Category)

Also,while Debugging in Thread Window, Under Category column There is a **Main Thread** which has only one Thread as shown here:

[image]

EDIT: My Colleague said that If Name is **Worker Thread** then its Non GUI thread.

When I use Observable.Start(From System.Reactive) instead of Task.Run, I get two Such Instances(with no-name), which defies one UI Thread Per window Concept :(

[image]

The Question is,

How can I Find the ***One*** Ui thread from the List?
or..Is Main Thread the UI Thread?(But its Managed ID is 0)

Any Leads on the above Questions will be Really Helpful!

Comment: Note that a UWP app can have [multiple UI threads](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/01/09/be-two-places-at-once-using-multiple-windows/). Also, I believe the main CoreWindow isn't usually on the main thread. (There's no reason it has to be.)

Comment: Instead of trying to find the UI thread, you could just schedule some work for the UI thread by using the CoreDispatcher.RunAsync: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_

Comment: @RaymondChen Completely agreed! UWP App can have Multiple UI Threads, One For Each Window. ie if the app has **n** Views or Windows there will be **n ** UI threads. My intention is to Find out which exactly is(are) UI thread(s).

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Yup as I have mentioned, its doable. But I wanna Create a custom TaskLibrary. For Debugging, I have to know exactly whether they are being executed in BackGround Thread. Thence this!

Comment: The question might be more useful to you (and others) if you would clearly state what you want to achieve with this TaskLibrary. You might get better help. (I am not telling you that this question is wrong but to me it looks like you might be on the wrong track) See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You should set up your library so that the caller tells you which dispatcher to use. That way, you won't be forced to guess.

Comment: @RaymondChen The question is valid. I'm currently debugging Edge UI lockup. I attach debugger and look at the threads list. Which thread is the UI thread that's locked up?

Comment: Why are you trying to find a specific UI thread? Trying to understand why you don't just utilize the CoreDispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

In (2) in the posting, using the dispatcher Run Async does not create a worker (thread pool) task. It creates a new task on the dispatcher context, which is a context containing just the UI thread.

Note that asynchrony and threading are different concepts. The task created by dispatcher Run Async is run asynchronously but on the same thread. That's probably why HasThreadAccess is returning true.

To create a task on a worker (thread pool) thread, you can use Task.Run. Note the thread-pool context has multiple threads, and these can be assigned to different processors, so it is possible that two tasks may run at the same time. Therefore, some firm of locking (such as SemaphoreSlim) is often needed.

sjb